# Consuming touches and sending them to nextResponder

Tags: ios, touch, viewcontroller

I have an app with a transparent view controller over an opaque view controller. The opaque view controller has a button. I want to get the touches in the transparent view controller and log them, and also see the button clicked. Is that possible?
When I try the [nextResponder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207287/whats-the-trick-to-pass-an-event-to-the-next-responder-in-the-responder-chain) solution it doesn't work. 
When I print out the nextResponder I see it's the UIWindow, is that ok?

The AppDelegate simply does this:

```
OpaqueViewController *someVC = [[OpaqueViewController alloc] init];
someVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.window addSubview:someVC.view];

TransparentViewController *panel = [[TransparentViewController alloc] init];
panel.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.window addSubview:panel.view];
```

So I tried this:

```
@implementation TransparentViewController
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

And I can't get the button on the OpaqueViewController to click...

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old question. Never the less I just struggled with the same problem. It seems that NextResponder is not the right approach on touches. Instead use:

```
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
```

One would expect it to behave the same, but the super class most perform some additional magic.

Comment: I don't know why nobody's upvoting this answer. It worked perfectly for me in mu Cocos2d-x project.