# UIView subview touch forward

Tags: ios, uiview

I have two custom UIViews (A and B respectively) each with a frame set to the same origin and same size.  They are both added to a parent UIView (C) as subviews.

I have a touch recognizer as part of A and B that listen for touches on certain spots.  If that touch is received, it raises a delegate up to the parent UIView saying it has been touched.  The issue is that since B is added after A, B never receives a touch event.

The A and B UIViews are single lines with endpoints.  They both recognize touches on the endpoints and raise up delegate notifications.  How do I add subviews and recognize touches on them with parent views on top?  It's like an exclusivity thing.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207287/whats-the-trick-to-pass-an-event-to-the-next-responder-in-the-responder-chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A is receiving touch events and B isn't though they're both children of C, then it's because A is claiming all touch events for itself, including those intended for B.

The solution is to override the pointInside:withEvent: method on A in order to determine whether it should accept the event for itself, like this:

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self pointIsInHotspot:point]) return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Where pointIsInHotspot is whatever tests you need to perform in order to determine if the point is on an active area within the view.

Answer (score 0):

Set `cancelsTouchesInView` to NO in your gesture recognizer.