# Button on a UITableviewCell's subview does not respond

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am implement a scorllable UITableview Cell and I get into a problem:

On the common tableview cell, I added a `scrollview`. On that `scrollview`, I added another cell called `socialcell`. I know it's weird to add a cell to another cell, but it doesn't matter and you can just take it as a view. On the `socialcell`, there is a `button`. The problem is that the `button` can't receive any touch event, and the touch is received by the tableview.

It's been checked that all of the views were added to their parent view correctly.

I have viewed the UI hierarchy and the button is right on the top. Is it the problem of iOS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Where you declared button action - i think you are declaring you button action with in table view cell class .

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980500/uiview-subview-touch-forward

Comment: Just make sure that you set self.tableView.delaysContentTouches  to NO and the scrollView.delaysContentTouches to NO.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved the problem, thanks to anyone who tried to help!

This is how I solved the problem:

It seems that the `scrollview` distracts the touch events of other views, and I override a function of `scrollview`:

```
-(id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
id hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
if (hitView == self) return nil;
else return hitView;}
```

And it did work.