# Tool bar button items not responding when searchDisplayController is active on ios7

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, toolbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

My application has searchDisplay Controller and a tool bar with Bar button items on it.My problem is that when i tap search button ,search results are shown but my Bar button doesn't respond to click event on ios 7.But the same thing works fine for ios 6.

Bar button works fine when i tap without searching.I understand that bar button is not reactive when my searchDisplay Controller is set active.
I am unable to find the reason and need to over come the issue.

Comment: Move your bar button above the searchDisplayController view?

Comment: @JohnWoods: ya its working above search bar.But i want it to be below the search bar.Im confused why its not working

Answer (score 0):

It's not working as your SearchDisplayController is handling the touch event and as such doesn't pass it through the responder chain, down to the bar view.

You can manually pass the event through so that your bar responds to the touch if required.

Check this out: [What's the trick to pass an event to the next responder in the responder chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207287/whats-the-trick-to-pass-an-event-to-the-next-responder-in-the-responder-chain)

Comment: can you pls give me some snippet to make my undestanding more clear??