# Override UIGestureRecognizer touchesBegan

Tags: swift, overriding, touch-event

I have 1 Main View and 1 *SubView*:

Main View > SubView

I think that the Main View is "stealing" the events from the *SubView*.

For example, when I tap on the *SubView*, only the **Main View GestureRecognizer** is fire.

Here is my custom **GestureRecognizer** (which intercepts every touch event):

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class MainGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {
    
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event);
        //nextResponder() ??
        
        state = UIGestureRecognizerState.Began;
    }
 
    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event);
        //nextResponder() ??
        
        state = UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed;
    }
 
    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event);
        //nextResponder() ??
        
        state = UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended;
    }
 
    override func touchesCancelled(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event);
        //nextResponder() ??
        
        state = UIGestureRecognizerState.Cancelled;
    }
}
```

Maybe I should use **nextResponder**, but I have only found Obj-C code like:

> [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
>
> [What's the trick to pass an event to the next responder in the responder chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207287/whats-the-trick-to-pass-an-event-to-the-next-responder-in-the-responder-chain)
>
> [Is there a way to pass touches through on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631427/is-there-a-way-to-pass-touches-through-on-the-iphone)

So the question is, what should I do to make the second event (the SubView Event) fire too?

Is there a function like **nextResponder** in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ôh ! Here is the Swift code for **nextResponder** :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26510277/4135158

Comment: Would you mind posting some code? I couldn't figure out how that link fit into solving your (and my) problem.