# How to send touch events to nextResponder in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, touch-event, uiresponder

## Background

I'm trying to make a `UICollectionViewCell` behave like a button (ie, do an animated dim on touch). I had the idea of just filling the cell with a `UIButton`. The button would then take care of the visual effect of being tapped. But then I would need to pass the touch event on to the parent (the `UICollectionViewCell`) so that the button does not just consume the event. That way I could handle it with the collection view's `didSelectItemAtPath`. The problem below is my attempt to figure out how to pass the event on.

## My problem

I came across [this Objective-C answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891216/3681880) for passing the touch event on:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; 
}
```

However, I got stuck when I tried to convert this to Swift:

```
class MyButton: UIButton {

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
        self.nextResponder() // ???
    }
}
```

The `nextResponder` method doesn't take any arguments, so how do I pass on the touch events?

I wasn't able to use related SO questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506148/swift-override-touchesbegan) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510110/i-cant-create-uiresponder-nextresponder-in-swift-ios)) to help me figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nextResponder` method returns an optional `UIResponder?`, so you can simply call `touchesBegan` on the returned object:

```
self.nextResponder()?.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
```

**Update: Swift 4.2**

```
self.next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
```

Comment: This solves the question that I asked. Unfortunately, my `UICollectionViewCell` still doesn't appear to be receiving the touch events. Unless you know what the problem may be right off hand, though, this probably calls for a new question.

Answer (score 2):

mmh02's answer updated to Swift 4.2

```
next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
```