# UIWebView Copy Paste

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, copy-paste

I am Handling`UIWebView` actions `Copy` and `paste` ..I don't know Exactly how it works..
What I need i do is...When I tap on link it should copy the `URL` and in `UiTextField` or `Browser bar` it should be able to paste ...

what I am doing is :

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if([title isEqualToString:@"Copy"]){ 

   NSURL *requestedURL = [request URL];
   NSString *link = [requestedURL absoluteString];
    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

    pasteboard.string = link;

    NSLog(@"paste is %@",pasteboard.string); // this does not give me the anything
  }
```

please let me know where i am going wrong in the copy method,,,and how it be pasted

Answer (score 1):

Go through this link:- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] containsPasteboardTypes:UIPasteboardTypeListString];
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]; 
if (pasteboard.string != nil) { [self insertText:pasteboard.string]; }
```

Comment: thanks..I made mistake in my code... if you could help me in this question then,,, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686406/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-not-working/14687134#14687134