# uibutton with touchesBegan

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use `touchesBegan:withEvent:` to get the touches of the user in the screen but when i touch a button this method isn't called. Is there any way to identify which button was clicked?

**edit:**

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint finger = [touch locationInView:self];
    int x = finger.x;
    int y = finger.y;

}
```

This is the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method. I gave each UIButton a tag number. And I did connect the UIButton in the interface builder.

Comment: How did you go about implementing this? We need a bit more info.

Comment: If you posted some code it would help, also, if you use InterfaceBuilder have you remembered to connect the outlets?

Comment: buttons consume the touches and do not pass it along. If you can tell what is it that you're trying to do, we can help you find an optimal solution.

Comment: i try to make an app that can know which UIButton was pressed or to get info when UIButton was pressed,and i dont want to give any UIButton a method or a method for all the UIButtons

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to pass touches through on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631427/is-there-a-way-to-pass-touches-through-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631427/is-there-a-way-to-pass-touches-through-on-the-iphone) question. Exactly what you need.

Comment: thx,the problem that when i use it the method that need to happen when the UIButton was press didn't happen