# drag UIView like apps in the home screen iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, drag

I have a view control and inside I plan to place some controls like buttons textbox etc...  I can drag my view along the x axis like:

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

with the following code:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if( [touch view] == ViewMain)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        displaceX = location.x - ViewMain.center.x;        
        displaceY = ViewMain.center.y;        
        startPosX = location.x - displaceX;
    }

    CurrentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

}


- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{



    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if( [touch view] == ViewMain)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        location.x =location.x - displaceX;
        location.y = displaceY;
        ViewMain.center = location;
    }  


}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    double time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]-CurrentTime;


    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if( [touch view] == ViewMain)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        location.x =location.x - displaceX;
        location.y = displaceY;
        ViewMain.center = location;
        double speed = (ViewMain.center.x-startPosX)/(time*2);
        NSLog(@"speed: %f", speed);

    }
}
```

not that I have to add the global variables:

```
float displaceX = 0;
float displaceY = 0;
float startPosX = 0;
float startPosY = 0;
double CurrentTime;
```

the reason why I created those variables is so that when I start dragging the view the view moves from the point where I touch it instead of from the middle.

Anyways if I touch a button or image the view will not drag even though the images have transparency on the background.  I want to be able to still be able to drag the view regardless if there is an image on top of the view. I where thinking that maybe I need to place a large transparent view on top of everything but I need to have buttons, images etc. I want to be able to drag a view just like you can with:

[image]

note that I was able to drag the view regardless of wither I first touched an app/image or text. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that if you touch a UIButton or a UIImageView with interaction enabled, it doesn't pass the touch along.
For the images, uncheck the `User Interaction Enabled`property in IB.
For the buttons that are causing touchesBegan:withEvent:, etc. to not get called, then look at the following link: [Is there a way to pass touches through on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631427/is-there-a-way-to-pass-touches-through-on-the-iphone).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider a different approach to this problem.  Rather than trying to manually manage the content scrolling yourself you would probably be better off using a `UIScrollView` with the `pagingEnabled` property set to YES.  This is the method Apple recommends (and it's probably the method used by Springboard.app in your last screenshot).  If you are a member of the iOS developer program check out the WWDC 2010 session on UIScrollView for an example of this.  I think they may have also posted sample code on developer.apple.com.