# touchesAnyObject not working as i thought it might

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Im using the following code:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    self.location = [touch locationInView:self.view];    
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(location));
}
```

In order to try and find where the user might touch the screen, and i thought that `[touches anyobject]` would allow it to detect where the user has touched the screen even if another object has been selected. However when I select a button it seems that it is not the case. Could anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIButtons by default "absorb" the touch, so you have to manually pass it along.

Check out this thread for more info:
[Is there a way to pass touches through on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631427/is-there-a-way-to-pass-touches-through-on-the-iphone)