# Dragging a tableview cell that contains uibuttons

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, touchesmoved

I'm trying to implement a uitableview that its rows can be dragged to right and left (and show something behind them).
The code works fine, I've implemented it using the following methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

My problem is that the rows also contain UIButtons that when clicking them- should be clicked but when dragging - should drag the entire cell.
I've found **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631427/is-there-a-way-to-pass-touches-through-on-the-iphone/)** solution. Basically to bubble up the events when clicking on the UIButtons:

```
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
[self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
```

But, it seems taht the event `touchesMoved` only bubbles once.

I've seen all sort of questions in this area. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798731/touchesmoved-with-uibutton-xcode-4-4-ios-5-1-1). But I don't see any solution or responses. 
**Any help, suggestion or creative workaround would be appreciated!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of implementing touchesBegan, etc. why not use a UIPanGestureRecognizer? I tested this with just a simple rectangular view which was mostly covered by a UIButton. The view was dragged, no matter where I touched, and the button method fired if I clicked over the button.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
    [self.theView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture]; //theView is IBOutlet for small view containing a button
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.currentViewFrame = self.theView.frame;
}

- (IBAction)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGPoint translate = [sender translationInView:self.view];

    CGRect newFrame = self.currentViewFrame;
    newFrame.origin.x += translate.x;
    newFrame.origin.y += translate.y;
    sender.view.frame = newFrame;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        self.currentViewFrame = newFrame;
}

-(IBAction)doClick:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"click");
}
```

Comment: I'm using a TableView with a custom cell. Do you think it would work there?

Comment: I think so -- try it out and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Just check to see which one was touched using the tag system.

Comment: How is that related? I can tell which UIButton was touched. I can't bubble the touchesMoved to the super view. It has nothing to do with which button was touched...