# touchesBegan not being called over a UIbutton

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, touches

The touchBegan method is not being called over my UIButton. I want both the UIButton and the touchesBegan method to share the touch. Is that possible? 
Right now when I click the button, only the button method is being called and it seems to "override" the touches method.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 // not called over button
}
```

How would you enable both methods?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631427/is-there-a-way-to-pass-touches-through-on-the-iphone

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE. Thanks!