# How to get coordinates of tap on UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, coordinates

I'm using this method, but it works only for my UIView subclass. If I tap on UITextView or UIButton or on any other object it's not display coordinates. How to get coordinates of tap on UITextView? And why this happening?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *userTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPos = [userTouch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Coordinates: (%f,%f)", currentPos.x, currentPos.y);
}
```

Comment: You might need to subclass your UITextView and apply the 2nd answer found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631427/is-there-a-way-to-pass-touches-through-on-the-iphone

Comment: It's works, but it's dont recognize single fast click (tap). I need to push mouse button for 0.2-0.3 second, then it works perfectly. Do you know why? Delay or something else?

Comment: Are you using scroll view? There is a property delaysContentTouches that you will want to adjust.

Comment: Yes, I'm using. How to adjust it?

Comment: set the scroll view delaysContentTouches property to NO

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in ViewDidLoad method,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapRecognized:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.textView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Implement above method

```
-(void)singleTapRecognized:(id)sender{
    CGPoint tapPoint = [sender locationInView:self.textView];
    NSLog(@"Coordinates: (%f,%f)", tapPoint.x, tapPoint.y);
}
```

Comment: I should add it to ViewController or to UITextView?