# Set UIButton state to selected when creating custom UIButton class

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

My UIButton has been created and it has the colors for the states I want.

However, when I click it, it does not remain selected.

All the code I am reading addresses the state of the button in the View Controller after an IB action. I do not yet understand the `touchesBegan` method either.

I have to repeat this 14 times and would like to avoid setting this for each one..

Edit: Code:

```
class AppointmentDatePickerAMButton: UIButton {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Selected)


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting your color for control state highlighted or selected? Remember UIButton has 4 states.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: And you are toggling between gray and red? does it ever turn blue? when?

Comment: @Mikael - I never get it to turn blue. I do not want to resort to IBActions.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you have to do is to add target action for the button, pass the button instance to that method and set on it `sender.selected = YES` if only selecting or `sender.selected = !sender.selected` if on/off behaviour wanted. In your code you defined how it should look like for selected state, then you only have to set control that state. Remember that button can combine multiple states at the same time (for example highlighted and selected).

Comment: This is the correct answer as `UIButton` does not remain in a selected state just by pressing it. It will toggle between states so you must set it in your code if you want to keep it selected after a user taps it,.

Comment: Totally agree with your comment. This is what I wanted to express in my answer :)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. I know I can do that.

Comment: so what is the problem then? according to your question yo don't know that.

Comment: @JulianKról - see answer below

Comment: @ovatsug25 this is the correct answer, you will have to set the state of your button if you want it to stay selected. You can recycle the code you have for your 14 buttons but each button will still need an action, whether they share the same action or not is up to you..

Comment: @rmp - see my answer, no need to create an action

Comment: @ovatsug25 see my comment to your answer. It may or may not work for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to UIButton:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    self.highlighted = true

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
    self.selected = !self.selected
    self.highlighted = false
}
```

Comment: This does not account for the various touch interactions a user can have on your button, just that the touch ended. If you don't care whether the user touched and dragged off or performed some other touch action that doesn't represent a true selection then this will work for you. Otherwise, this is not a valid answer.

Comment: the current implementation might be harmful for the standard button behaviour [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5891216/3151066) and then [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:) downvoting for a good try of help is not nice!

Comment: Even though it might work (haven't tested that solution) this is not a common approach so colleagues in a team or someone who will maintain the code might be very surprised :P

Comment: Yet another question, why setting selection on ending touch not with the begin? because colors won't animate properly? that shouldn't be the reason

Comment: @JulianKról - added the call to super which should clear this up for you.

Comment: you do not have to call super for me :) anyway I think that setting logging for stetting states in UIButton is a bad practice.

Comment: @JulianKról - FYI, opinions don't matter on SO unless they inform the answer. I wouldn't have down voted your question if it proved that what I wanted wasn't possible. but you also didn't really read the question because I was pretty clear about not wanting to do anything through an IBAction unless it was the only way

Comment: where was you clear about "not wanting to do anything through an IBAction unless it was the only way" ? My answer answered your question and is correct and common approach. Be clear next time you ask a question. Answer doesn't have to prove that everything else is totally wrong... Moreover your initial implementation was wrong