# Determine whether there is any touch in view hierarchy

Tags: ios, uikit

What's the best way to determine whether there is any active touch happening in a view hierarchy? Something like:

`view.hasTouches`

returns `true` if `view` or any of its descendant has active touches.

To those who would suggest using `UIResponder`'s touch event handling API like `touchesBegan`, notice that `view` doesn't receive these calls if one of its descendant is handling the touch events.

Comment: Do you have a specific use case? The `UIViewController` should call the `touchesBegan` for all its subviews.

Comment: @Rikh Add a `UIButton` to your view. Tap the button. See whether your `UIViewController. touchesBegan` is called.

Comment: Ah so you specifically want to understand for `UIButton`. Probably because it has a parent as `UIControl` which eats up the touch it behaves a bit differently. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631427/is-there-a-way-to-pass-touches-through-on-the-iphone . It is in Objective-C but the logic still holds.

Comment: @Rikh I don't want to catch all touch events in all descendants and pass them up. For one it is too tedious. Secondly I may not have control of all the descendants anyway. I need a top-down approach.

Comment: Ah well, I unfortunately can't think of any possible solution that may help out in a top-down approach.

Comment: @Rikh me either, that's why I ask here:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` methods in `UIViewController` as follows:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var isTouching = false
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        isTouching = true
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        isTouching = false
    }
}
```